# How can i make models in django with form input

Tags: django, django-models

I Want to make a backend service website, for that I am working in **django**  and want to make django models but with form input,
if a user create a table in my frontend I want to create a table or model in data base how can i do it?

Hello stackies ,

I Want to make a backend service website, for that I am working in **django**  and want to make django models but with form input,
if a user create a table in my frontend I want to create a table or model in data base how can i do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot create models dynamically because this would require migrations to apply the changes.
I'd recommend that you store your customer information in a structured JSON, that you can store in a PostgreSQL field, for example. Or you can jump to a document-based database, such as MongoDB.